PHP sessions and mySQL database - no error given with SELECT but doesnt work
I am using an HTML form to collect username and password for a login authentication process with PHP and mySQL.  My PHP script includes the following code for user authentication:
    session_cache_expire(36000);
    session_start();
    
    ...
    
    // database connection code goes here which is all correct
    
    ...
    
    $sqldo="SELECT userid, usern, passw, authorization FROM db.table WHERE ( usern = :username AND passw = :password )";
    $stmtdo = $dbh->prepare($sqldo);
    $stmtdo->bindParam(':username', $myusername);
    $stmtdo->bindParam(':password', $mypassword);
    $stmtdo->execute();
    $rows = $stmtdo->rowCount();
                                                
    if($rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;  
        while ($rowLogin = $stmtdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<p>test<p>';
            echo '<p>test 2'.$rowLogin[userid];
            
            ...
            
        }
    }

"test" prints
the "test 2" line does not output anything.  No error is provided, nothing.  So it is difficult to troubleshoot.  The $rowLogin[userid] value is just blank.
Any assistance would help.  Thanks

Presumably the query did not match any rows in the database then

No it does .  It matches 1 username correctly when I enter this SELECT statement directly into mySQL.  The SELECT syntax structure seems to be correct.

$rowLogin['userid'] with quotes , or print_r($rowLogin) to verify keys

Based on your code, it should display the data of $rowLogin[userid] (both $rowLogin[userid] and  $rowLogin['userid'] can be used) It is because $rows == 1 is true and I believe userid would not be a blank data too. So there must be something missing (not posted) in your question - please post a minimal reproducible example.

In respone to Mate - thank you for replying... print_r() outputs the appropriate keys

Great. Did you print what you want?  otherwise add  print_r() output

no it didnt work... nothing outputs.  I provided more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78288066/php-and-mysql-unable-to-debug-or-execute-no-error-given-on-a-select-query-us

Just a warning about using PDOStatement::rowCount() on SELECT statements (from the manual): "For statements that produce result sets, such as SELECT, the behavior is undefined and can be different for each driver. Some databases may return the number of rows produced by that statement (e.g. MySQL in buffered mode), but this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Skip the rowCount() and while loop all together. Just do: $user = $stmtdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);. If $user is false, no match was found, otherwise $user will contain the matched user and you can use it directly. Less complexity in your code == much easier to follow, understand and debug. It also decreases possible points of failure.
